# LC filter pole in RHP

Tags: filter

I am trying to derive the poles in an LC filter:

[image]

But I see that one of my poles is in the LHP and the other is in the RHP plane, both fully imaginary. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like both poles are on the jw axis (as they should be without resistance in the circuit).  I think you're confusing the upper and lower half planes with the left and right half planes.

See this answer for more info: [Very basic question about under damped oscillation frequency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/357094/very-basic-question-about-under-damped-oscillation-frequency)

Comment: But from a bode plot view, the impact of a +jw pole and a -jw pole is the same? They will appear as a double pole and give a -90 -90 = -180 deg phase shift?

Comment: @alayoiskgfbfqhxjiw Yes, they will result in 180 degrees of eventual phase shift and -40 dB/decade of roll off in the magnitude response.

Answer (score 0):

Poles are expected to be imaginary anyway because there isn't such thing as complex inductance and complex capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the pole-zero diagram looks like for your 2nd-order, low-pass filter: -

[image]

Note that **your** poles will be on the \$j\omega\$ axis top and bottom. They will, as damping is introduced, both move leftwards along the circular dotted trajectory in the diagram. Image from my [basic website](http://www.stades.co.uk/). If you are interested, this is what the pole-zero diagram looks like in 3D (now incorporating the bode plot): -

[image]

Just the positive-frequency pole is shown for reasons of clarity.